# Docker: how to log out from all remote registries?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I thought the `docker logout` command would log me out from the remote private docker registry I had just logged in but it doesn't.

Before trying to logout:

```
$ cat ~/.docker/config.json

{
    "auths": {
            "rg.nl-ams.scw.cloud": {
                    "auth": "da2kleGhoPNjVj...pLri69="
...
```

After the command

```
$ docker logout

$ cat ~/.docker/config.json

{
    "auths": {
            "rg.nl-ams.scw.cloud": {
                    "auth": "da2kleGhoPNjVj...pLri69="
...
```

This is problematic because when I then launch `run` commands, docker tries to pull an image from this remote registry but I don't want that to happen. I don't want docker to be aware of this registry anymore. What should I do?

I see now that `docker logout` by default logs you out from some "default server" that is apparently "https://index.docker.io/v1/". How do I logout from all servers? Do I really have to write a script for this?
I don't want to rely on a particular server name, I just want to make sure the docker client is not logged in anywhere so that I can run tests in a clean and repeatable way.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logout

Answer (score 5):

Use this and specify remote private registry
**docker logout URL**
for example ***docker logout localhost:8080*** (to log out of a registry on your local host)

Answer (score 3):

I use this script:

```
for url in $(cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq -r '.auths | keys | .[]'); do docker logout $url; done
```

It reads the docker config.json file, parses the keys inside the auths, and uses them to logout. You might need to install `jq`.